# How to make a safe phone number verification after register in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to design a register system which after user submit the required fields(included "phone-number" and ...),he/she has to verify his/her phone number via the code which has been sent to his/her phone number.
My question is how to send the phone number right after registration to confirmNumber method?
I don't want to send the phone number via GET method because user can modify it

and here is my code in codeigniter:

```
public function register()
{
    $request = \Config\Services::request();
    if($request->getMethod() == 'post'){
        $validation =  \Config\Services::validation();
        if ($validation->run($request->getPost(),'register')){
            $this->save($request->getPost());
            //how to send the phone number to confirmNumber method?
        }else{
            $data['validation'] = $validation->getErrors();
            return view('/auth/register',$data);
        }

    }else{
        return view('/auth/register');
    }
}


public function cofirmNumber()
{
    //this method will return the view which confirms phone number
}

private function save(array $array)
{
    //this method save user to the database before number verification
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to ask again for the phone number you already have? Aren't you using sessions or a database?

Comment: No at the first form user enters the phone number and after the form is submitted with out any errors , another form will appear which user has to enter the code which has been sent to his phone number via SMS

Comment: By the way after the first form submission the user will be saved in the database, and then the confirmation form will appear

Comment: that's the way is in my mind but if you think it's wrong i would be happy if you tell me the better way

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol. Sessions were invented many years ago to precisely solve that and it's the industry standard. You could figure out a different mechanism but, why care? https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: you mean i should save the phone number in a session and use it in confirmNumber method?                                                                                                                        sorry if i've got it wrong

Comment: You can store the number in session when you first get it and use that ever since. In another words, you only need to ask for it once.

Comment: aw okay thank you so much.sorry if my question was simple...i'm kinda new in programming world

Comment: There's nothing wrong in learning. I only was confused because frameworks like Codeigniter typically have sessions as first class component.